# How to change a lot of items using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows

This is my items table in mysql

```
----------- -------------
|    id    |    k_id    |
----------- -------------
|    1     | 12,2,65,98 |
----------- -------------
|    2     | 2,5,77,234 |
----------- -------------
|    3     | 48,125,119 |
----------- -------------
```

And this table has 120000 rows.

now I want to change all values in `k_id` column like this one:

```
----------- ---------------------
|    id    |        k_id        |
----------- ---------------------
|    1     | "12","2","65","98" |
----------- ---------------------
|    2     | "2","5","77","234" |
----------- ---------------------
|    3     | "48","125","119"   |
----------- ---------------------
```

How can do this?
Can do this using php?
Can do this in phpmyadmin in cpanel?

please help me with best way.

Comment: What's the reasoning for adding quotes to the values?  Are the values always numeric?

Comment: Yes, the values are numeric always

Comment: What's the reasoning behind having comma-separated values in these rows?

Comment: why are you doing this if you want to use this list in a query just use FIND_IN_SET()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET k_id = CONCAT('"', REPLACE(k_id,',','","'), '"');
```

Comment: @user4142853 you should look at my answer about normalizing your database... its a bad idea to store data in that way

Answer (score 3):

Did not check it, but something like this

```
UPDATE tablename SET k_id = CONCAT('"', REPLACE(k_id, ',', '","'), '"')
```

Comment: I remember last time I used REPLACE without checking it thoroughly, it screwed up my whole DB table! Arguments should be `fieldname, findstring, replacestring`..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the data in separate strings like that so that you can use it in an IN() statement... its not necessary as MySQL has a method to handle that exact type of data (aka comma separated list)

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('5', k_id) > 0;
```

this will return id 3.. however I would recommend you normalize your database... storing comma separated values is always a bad idea..

### Normalize It!

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS normalized_table AS 
(   SELECT
      id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(k_id, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) column2
    FROM test
    JOIN(SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) n
        ON LENGTH(REPLACE(k_id, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(k_id)-n.digit
    ORDER BY id, n.digit
);

DROP table test; -- test is just a dummy name for the name of your table
CREATE table test (id int, k_id int);
INSERT INTO test (id, k_id) 
SELECT id, k_id FROM normalized_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this
Use Concat function and replace function in mysql

```
update TableName set k_id=CONCAT('"', REPLACE(',', '","', k_id, '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to get all the values, do the string manipulation in PHP, and reinsert - but I like Cheery's way better.  Though if you need to put your integers into strings in your database, it sounds like you might have a different problem somewhere else that could be addressed without changing all the values like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
    try

UPDATE my_table SET k_id = CONCAT('"', REPLACE(k_id, ',', '","'), '"')

    UPDATE my_table SET  k_id = CONCAT( k_id, ", ", "999") ;

        //Use the function mysql CONCAT_WS() -> Concatenate With Separator

    UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET FIELD_NAME = CONCAT_WS(",",k_id)
```